# reboot scss bootstrap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap, wordpress, scss

Tengo problemas con el reboot.scss de bootstrap mediante el css pido el cambio de la etiqueta de  a color blanco y el reboot.scss se antepone a mi cambio, no se a que se debe esto.
Nota: estoy practicando con wordpress, por eso la imagen de las functions

[image: Imagenes de las paginas con css]

[image: Imagenes de las paginas function wordpress]

Comment: aplicale !important

Answer (score 1):

para que tu css sea reconocido, tienes que usar la etiqueta `!importat`, para que sobreescriba el estilo.

```
#div{
background:white !important;
}
```

Comment: No esta tomando en cuenta el  !important;

Answer (score 0):

Logre resolverlo, simplemente cambie el bootstrap.min.css por el bootstrap.css